# How does the client get the DATABASE_URL?

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

I have a java application, and I want it to be able read from a postgres database I added to my heroku app.
I am able to access the DATABASE_URL environment variable from inside my Node.js app, heroku dashboard, and also from my heroku CLI.

This documentation says that a client should be able to access the database:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku
But how does the client (a java application running on a different machine, without Heroku CLI installed) get the DATABASE_URL? Sure, I am not meant to hardcode it into the java application, but I'm struggling to understand how its meant to work.

Comment: How does it get the url now?

Comment: I hardcode it into a getConnection() method which is usually supposed to look at an environment variable. Is the client machine supposed to use the heroku CLI to set the environment variable? So every client needs the heroku CLI?

Comment: Define a system variable for your local environment

Comment: @Beppe Is there a way I can do that programmatically, without using heroku CLI? Is that really the way a client machine learns about where my postgres database is?

Comment: @MaxKessler, in a ideal solution, you should not open your database to be accessed directly. But if you have to and you may have to change your db location, then you have to have a fully qualified domain name, your env file will know the fqdn, even if you change your server location, it would not impact your product, but  you must not store user name and password on client end tool.

Comment: @MaxKessler Are you running locally Postgres for development or are you trying to connect to the Heroku Postgres?

Comment: @Beppe I am not running Postgres locally, I made the database through the heroku dashboard. What I am really after is some way for the a user who downloads my Java application to interact with my heroku app. Based on the other answers, and the fact that the documentation assumes that any machine which is going to connect to the database has the heoku CLI, I assume this is wrong.